# What happens when we call ArrayList.add() method?

Tags: java, arraylist

When we call `ArrayList.add()` method, does it create a new object and add it to the list or does it adds the referenced object to the list?

For example: suppose we have two `ArrayList` as follows:

`ArrayList<ClassA> a1` and `ArrayList<ClassA> a2`. If I run the code:

`a2.add(a1.get(i))` will it create a new object and then add it to `a2` or it will refer to the same object from two different lists?

It is not the copy of

> Is Java pass by value or pass by reference question?

because I want to know the internal working of `ArrayList.add()` method, that does it create an object copy of the parameter passed or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @Pillar it's about how `ArrayList.add()` method works.

Comment: There's no reason to be specific about `add`. All methods work the same in this regard.

Comment: Its not about how add is taking in the parameter. It's about what it does with the parameter when it receives it, does it create an object copy (of the parameter passed) and then adds or does it use the same object (parameter passed) and then adds it to the list. Now I know the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what the other question is asking about and what the answers explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will refer to the same object in two different lists.

Of course, you can always verify this with some debugging effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass references or primitives to a method.  This method is no exception.

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 String s = "Hello";
 list.add(s); // pass the reference.
```

> a2.add(a1.get(i)) will it create a new object and then add it to a2 or it will refer to the same object from two different lists?

This will mean both Lists have a copy of the same reference (which will point to the same object)

Answer (score 2):

It will refer to the same object from those two different lists, which means if you edit that object from one place, another also gets impacted.

If you dont want that, consider making that class `immutable`